# flutter CocoaPods err (running pod install)

Tags: dart, flutter

When I run flutter run,   CocoaPods' errr , Error running pod install

flutter stable,
updata pod, CocoaPods

```
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing
    Analyzing dependencies
    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `barcode_scan` from `.symlinks/plugins/barcode_scan/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_full_pdf_viewer` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_full_pdf_viewer/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_record` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_record/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `flutter_vedio_compress` from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_vedio_compress/ios`
    [!] No podspec found for `flutter_vedio_compress` in `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_vedio_compress/ios`
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:825:in `fetch_external_source'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:804:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:803:in `each'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.6.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:803:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I have stopped receiving the error while executing pod install, when I altered some of the dependencies in pubspec.yaml. What I have done was referring to the dependency's git link instead of its version number.

To make it more clear instead of:

```
barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
```

I have written:

```
barcode_scan:
  git: git://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_barcode_reader.git
```